# is it correct to say "impart money"

Tags: meaning, phrase-usage

I know impart means "to give" and is used commonly with knowledge, as in "impart knowledge"...but can I say that a government scheme "imparted money" to the beneficiaries?

Comment: I suppose you could, but I don't know why  you'd want to. [Nobody seems to](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=gave+money%2Cimparted+money%2Cdonated+money%2Cbequeathed+money&year_start=1920&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3).

Comment: *Impart* is normally used with non-concrete things, like knowledge, wisdom, a sense of security, and what have you. It would be very strange to use it with respect to money, and to do so would likely flag you right away as a non-native speaker or someone otherwise not very capable in English.

Comment: Dispense is a better fit.

Answer (score 1):

According to the  [Cambrigde Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/impart), **to impart** means:

> - to communicate information to someone:
>
>   - e.g., to impart the bad news: *I was rather quiet as I didn't feel I had much wisdom to **impart** on the subject.*
> - to give something a particular feeling, quality, or taste:
>
>   - *Preservatives can **impart** colour and flavour to a product.*
> - to give a feeling or quality to something, or to make information known to someone:
>
>   - *If the movie has any lesson to **impart**, it’s that parents shouldn’t aim for perfection.*

As you can see, none of the meanings involves money (or anything that you can touch, for that matter).